# Http 504 error while accessing URL from websphere

Tags: java, websphere-7

I'm trying to hit a URL and get response by using `java.net.URL` by writing a java class and deploying it in websphere 7.
I have ran this class successfully on local machine,development server using putty and local websphere server by calling it from a jsp.

Now if I try to run the same on development websphere server, I'm getting the error :
Server returned HTTP response code: 504 for URL: http://XX.XX.XX.XX:9080/smcfs/interop/InteropHttpServlet

I'm not able to understand why I'm able to get response in all three scenario but not in the case of development server.
Do I need to do any configuartion changes in websphere like security or anything ?

Here is the part of code where exception is thrown:

```
BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
               while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                   response += line;
               }
```

`connection.getInputStream()` is throwing the exception.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: As you are getting 504 , it clearly means that you are not getting any response from the requested web server as request is going timed out .

It seems like that there might be some proxy or firewall installed on the dev server that is blocking this request. - Thanks

Comment: If there is any proxy/firewall setting on the dev server, why I'm able to get response when I tested the class on the same server through putty ? Please throw some light. Thanks !

Comment: Try executing the request locally from the development WebSphere's machine. This might negate a proxy / DNS intervening.

Comment: I am having the same problem (504 after a long wait). I'm wondering if there is some security manager blocking URL connections from within classes loaded by the App/WebServer. Can someone throw some light on this. Im using Tomcat 7.

Comment: I also getting same issue, Same apps in out staging env it's working fine and production it's give 504 error, only difference in both server it in production we use https & rds database instance, in staging we not have this, Is any one have idea please reply me